# Regular Expression for re-verification

Tags: regex

I am trying to validate verification question and this is the regular expressin I have, I am not what this mean but this expression not allowing spaces

```
^\S+$
```

For example if I enter 'Test Me', this expresson says it is not valid.. How do I fix this to allow spaces?

Comment: Well, what all do you want to allow in your question?

Comment: The ONLY thing that regex is doing is ensuring that there is not white space characters in the string. EDIT: sorry, and it's also ensuring it's not empty implicitly because it's using + instead of *

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity depending on regex flavour it can also check that the expression resides between line boundaries. See RegexOptions.Multiline here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx

Comment: @zespri - For clarity: most flavors have a multiline option. But it requires applying the option - .NET would not apply `^` and `$` to line boundaries by default.

Comment: I answered your question to the best of my abilities but could you be a little more specific as to what the regex should match

Answer (score 2):

What exactly are you trying to match?

- `^` matches the beginning of the string
- `$` matches the end of the string
- `+` allows multiple occurances of the last expression
- `\S` stands for anything but a whitespace
- `\s` stands for white-spaces

The expression you have will match any string containing only non-white-space characters. If you could express what exactly you're trying to match, I could help you with it.

Comment: Well, I don't have enough reputation points to comment on a question. This is the only way I can communicate with the questioner. Thanks for the vote down, I'm farther away from a possibility of commenting.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 it was different when I commented

Comment: @aaronman - Only after getting at least 200 reputation on one of those sites.

Answer (score 2):

```
                               ^\S+$
                               ^^ ^^
                               || ||
^  start of string-------------+| ||
\S anything but a whitespace----+ ||
+  one or more of what precedes---+|
$  end of string-------------------+
```

(visit [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info) for a larger reference)

Not sure what you want to change, really, since this regular expressions seems to have been written for the sole purpose of *not* allowing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it does not match is because you are not allowing white space characters in your string with `\S` 
something that might serve you better is:

`^[\w\s]+$`

`\w`  is equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_]

`\s` matches whitespace

keep in mind that this regex will not allow punctuation, if you want that you may be better off using `^.+$`

Comment: No punctuation? My name contains a "-" ... would that never be a valid answer?

Comment: @Cyborgx37 this is actually validation for a security question not a name, but I did add to my answer

Comment: "What is your father's name?" is a pretty common verification question.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 as I said I changed it, but I thought he was trying to validate the question not the answer

Comment: *"I am not what this mean but this expression not allowing spaces"* - I think you'll need to use a little creative interpretation. English does not appear to be a first language here. I believe verifying an answer would be a far more common situation then verifying a question, but you never know. :)

Answer (score 1):

`^` means "start of the string"

`\S` is a special keyword in Regex that denotes "non-white space characters"

`+` means find the previous one or more times

`$` means "end of the string"

So in English, this Regex says: **starting at the start of the string, find me ONLY non-white space characters one or more times before the end of the string.** This is why it doesn't permit white space.

Comment: `\S` is not specific to .NET Regex.

Comment: Also `\S` matches **non**-whitespace

Comment: You're right, but it applies to the .NET implementation of Regex.

Comment: In most regular expression engines, `\S` means "non-whitespace" and `\s` means "whitespace"

Comment: Thank you all. Updated. Didn't realize `\S` differed from `\s`

Comment: I don't think 's' allowing white spaces. I just tried ^\s+$ and enter two words with white space in between, and it failed.